# Dealing with "random" POST data

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key

I have a page that pulls 5 random rows from a table. It looks similar to the below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[1]' value = 'y'><label for='1'>Yes</label> </td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[1]' value = 'n'><label for='1'>No</label> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[8]' value = 'y'><label for='8'>Yes</label> </td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[8]' value = 'n'><label for='8'>No</label> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[2]' value = 'y'><label for='2'>Yes</label> </td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[2]' value = 'n'><label for='2'>No</label> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[6]' value = 'y'><label for='6'>Yes</label> </td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[6]' value = 'n'><label for='6'>No</label> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[3]' value = 'y'><label for='3'>Yes</label> </td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name='bills[3]' value = 'n'><label for='3'>No</label> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This returns an array that looks like the following,

```
Array
(
    [bills] => Array
        (
            [6] => y
            [2] => n
            [5] => n
            [1] => y
            [8] => y
        )

)
```

By using a `foreach($_POST['bills'] as $bill)` statement I can loop through that array, but how do I get the value of the id, and its respective answer? In the above case, 6, 2, 5, 1, 8.

Comment: Change `foreach($_POST['bills'] as $bill)` to `foreach($_POST['bills'] as $key => $bill)`, the $key will be the key (number) of the item in the array.

Comment: Reading the PHP docs would have provided an immediate answer to this question, without losing the time to write it: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Include the key on your **`foreach`** construct like this

```
foreach($_POST['bills'] as $bill=>$answer)
{
echo "The value of $bill is $answer\n"; $bill will be 6,2,5,1,8 and $answer will be y,n,n,y,y
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
The value of 6 is y
The value of 2 is n
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4
);

while($element = current($array)) {
    echo key($array)."\n";
    next($array);
}
?>
```

**OR**

```
foreach($_POST['bills'] as $bill=>$answer)
{
    echo "$bill and $answer\n"; 
}
```